# MAMP -- MySQL Server -- LION Problems

Tags: mysql, osx-lion, mamp

Is anyone else having trouble getting with their mysql server not starting with lion.  Sometimes it starts sometimes it doesn't and it's really making me mad.  This never happened until I started using lion.  If anyone else has had this problem or knows a solution let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im going to go out on a limb here and say that it isn't working because of Skype.

If you were running Skype before starting up MAMP then this will cause apache to not start up.

This is due to the fact that both MAMP and Skype uses port 80. Just close Skype and apache should work again. Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't believe that.  Thank you.  Works perfect now.